# Expo/React Native Testing Library - Can not find test ID

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

looking for some assistance with some tests of mine. Starting with some basic text content tests. The following are snippets of my code for the Landing screen and the test I'm working on at the moment. I have a custom Text component as well that I'm using for some basic styles.

Text.tsx

```
import {
  TextProps as Props,
  StyleSheet,
  Text as SystemText,
} from 'react-native';

import useIsDarkMode from '@hooks/utils/useIsDarkMode';

import { theme } from '@theme/theme';

interface TextProps extends Props {
  text: string;
}

const Text = ({ text, style, ...rest }: TextProps) => {
  const isDarkMode = useIsDarkMode();

  return (
    <SystemText
      style={[
        {
          color: isDarkMode ? theme.colors.white : theme.colors.black,
          ...styles.text,
        },
        style,
      ]}
      allowFontScaling={false}
      {...rest}
    >
      {text}
    </SystemText>
  );
};

export default Text;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    includeFontPadding: false,
    fontSize: theme.fontSizes.sm,
    fontFamily: theme.fontFamily.regular,
  },
});
```

Landing.tsx

```
const Landing = () => {
  const navigation = useAppNavigation<'AuthStack'>();
  const { triggerHaptic } = useHaptics();

  const navigateToEnterEmail = () => {
    triggerHaptic();
    navigation.navigate('EnterEmail');
  };

  return (
    <SafeViewContainer>
      <View style={styles.mainView}>
        <View style={styles.headingView}>
          <Text text="My title" style={styles.title} testID="landing-title" />
          <Text
            text="My subtitle"
            style={styles.subtitle}
            testID="landing-subtitle"
          />
        </View>
        <View>
          <PrimaryButton
            text="Get started"
            style={styles.text}
            onPress={navigateToEnterEmail}
            testID="get-started-button"
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeViewContainer>
  );
};
```

Landing.test.tsx

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

import Landing from '@screens/AuthScreens/Landing';

describe('Landing', () => {
  it('renders the proper title and subtitle', async () => {
    const landingScreen = (
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Landing />
        </NavigationContainer>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    );

    render(landingScreen);

    const landingTitle = await screen.getByTestId('landing-title');

    expect(landingTitle).toHaveTextContent('My title');
  });
});
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Landing › renders the proper title and subtitle

    Unable to find an element with testID: landing-title

      17 |     render(landingScreen);
      18 |
    > 19 |     const landingTitle = await screen.getByTestId('landing-title');
         |                                       ^
      20 |
      21 |     expect(landingTitle).toHaveTextContent('My title');
      22 |   });
```

These are the packages that I have installed:

```
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "^48.0.1",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.0.0-rc.0",
```

Comment: I think you need to use `data-testid` instead of `testID`

Comment: Have you used `screen.debug()` after `render(landingScreen)? Do you see the RN elements rendered?

Comment: @WebbH `data-testid` doesn't seem to be an option. Putting it there also doesn't affect the test result unfortunately. @cdallava, doing that shows me the safe area provider component but not my Landing component. Looking into this option now, will update if I find the problem!

Comment: Did you try ```render(<Landing />)``` ? and use ```await screen.findByTestId('landing-title')```, I don't understand why you create landingScreen, your landingScreen is <Landing />.

Comment: @AdrienMasson If I don't provide the navigation and safe area wrappers that the screen itself uses, it errors out on rendering.

Comment: And did you try to replace ```await screen.getByTestId('landing-title');``` by ```await screen.findByTestId('landing-title')``` ?